# How to make the parent node to appear in the middle of 2 children regardless of pyramide level?

Tags: php, html, css

This markup:

```
 <ul>
       <li>
        <a href="#">root</a>
        <ul>
           <li>
           <a href="#">root</a>
           <ul>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">child 1</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">child 2</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

To this:

```
                  ________  
                 |        | 
                 |  test1 | 
                 |________| 
       ________              ________
      |        |            |        |
      |  test2 |            |  test3 |
      |________|            |________|
 ________   ________   ________   ________
|        | |        | |        | |        |
|  test4 | |  test5 | |  test6 | |  test7 |
|________| |________| |________| |________|
```

I have a php script that creates the above markup, the question is how to make the parent node to appear in the middle of 2 children regardless of pyramide level?

Comment: I do not understand this question at all

Comment: I'am asking about how to put visually the parent node relative to his childs

Comment: You have explained what you are trying to achieve quite poorly. Maybe you should redraw your diagrams so that the names in the code match the names in the diagrams

Answer (score 0):

Use table to design... design third row yourself

```
  <table align="center">
      <tr margin-left="10px">
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">root</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#">root</a>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">root</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=ADCdKwlQv8)

Comment: Just no. Should never use tables for layouts and positioning.